# React : Configuration files

Tags: reactjs, configuration

I'd like to uses configuration files for a react application but actually it don't work.
Here the list of my files :

package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build NODE_ENV=production",
  }
```

api.ts :

```
import config from 'config'
console.log(config.get('ApiURl'))
```

config/production.json :

```
{
  "ApiUrl" : "http://localhost:56205/api/v1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.env.ENV_VAR` to get a environnement variable, with this you can make a config handler like this

```
"ApiUrl": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'http://your/api/for/production' : 'http://your/api/for/dev'
```